# Google Sheets: Count Number of Times in Past 12 Months

Tags: google-sheets, count

I am trying to write a formula in Google Sheets to count the number of times a package was sold in the previous 12 months.

The Package Name is in Column A on my Results Page.

On the Data Page, the Package Name shows up in Column G and the Date Sold in Column M.

[Results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkwZt.jpg)
[Data Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeeO4.jpg)

Looking to count the number of times each package was sold in the past 12 months

Answer (score 0):

> On the Data Page, that Package Name shows up in Column G and the Date Sold shows up in Column M.

You can try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Data!G:G=package_name,ISBETWEEN(Data!M:M,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-12,TODAY()),TODAY()))
```

Comment: This did not work -- I got the following error message: Error
Function ISBETWEEN parameter 2 value is 89979. It should be less than or equal to value of Function ISBETWEEN parameter 3 with 45175.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(Data!G:G=package_name,ISBETWEEN(Data!M:M,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-12,DAY(TODAY())),TODAY()))`